# How to press/click the button using Selenium if the button does not have the Id?

Tags: selenium-rc, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide, buttonclick

I have 2 buttons Cancel and Next button on the same page but it has only one id (see the below code). I wanted to press Next but every time it is identifying the cancel button only not Next button. How to resolve this issue?

```
<td align="center">
     <input type="button" id="cancelButton" value="Cancel" title="cancel" class="Submit_Button" style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 160);">
     <input type="submit" value="Next" title="next" class="Submit_Button">
</td>
```

Comment: What are you using? Selenium RC or WebDriver (Selenium 2)? Which language are you using? Java? C#? Python? or what?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In Selenium IDE you can do:

```
Command   |   clickAndWait
Target    |   //input[@value='Next' and @title='next']
```

It should work fine.

Answer (score 23):

Use [xpath](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/) selector (here's quick [tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_intro.asp)) instead of id:

```
#python:
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox

YOUR_PAGE_URL = 'http://mypage.com/'
NEXT_BUTTON_XPATH = '//input[@type="submit" and @title="next"]'

browser = Firefox()
browser.get(YOUR_PAGE_URL)

button = browser.find_element_by_xpath(NEXT_BUTTON_XPATH)
button.click()
```

Or, if you use "vanilla" Selenium, just use same xpath selector instead of button id:

```
NEXT_BUTTON_XPATH = '//input[@type="submit" and @title="next"]'
selenium.click(NEXT_BUTTON_XPATH)
```

Answer (score 5):

use the text and value attributes instead of the id

```
driver.findElementByXpath("//input[@value='cancel'][@title='cancel']").click();
```

similarly for Next.

Answer (score 2):

For Next button you can use xpath or cssSelector as below:

xpath for Next button: //input[@value='Next']

cssPath for Next button: input[value=Next]

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use only identifier as elements locators. You can use a few ways to find an element. Read [this article](http://www.qaautomation.net/?p=188) and choose the best for you.

Comment: But after reading you should know what to do, when the element has not got an 'id' attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can use xpath for for identifying that element.

Answer (score 0):

```
    You can achieve this by using cssSelector 
    // Use of List web elements:
    String cssSelectorOfLoginButton="input[type='button'][id='login']"; 
    //****Add cssSelector of your 1st webelement
    //List<WebElement> button 
    =driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(cssSelectorOfLoginButton));
    button.get(0).click();

    I hope this work for you
```